# How do I obtain the AppData or equivalent folder path in C++ that works on Linux and Windows?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, appdata

I am making a game and I'm using the `AppData\Roaming` folder to store the file that contains the high score. I'm using the `_dupenv_s()` function to get the path to this folder.

However, on Linux the `_dupenv_s()` function throws an error: `‘_dupenv_s’ was not declared in this scope`, even though the code is completely the same (other than `\\` being converted to `/`, but that shouldn't matter).

I made sure to include all the necessary libraries such as `<stdlib.h>`, so that probably isn't the problem.

I could make different versions for Linux and Windows but I'd like the code to be the same for both operating systems.

Is there a way to get the path to `AppData\Roaming` or equivalent folder (e. g. `~/.local/`) in C++?

Comment: When developing for multiple platforms. Create an abstract baseclass (interface) with methods that model WHAT you want to do (e.g. safe a temp file). And then provide different implementations on different platforms. Added bonus : you can inject mocks during unit tests (unit tests will be important for you when you are developing a big project like a game)

Comment: Here's an interesting discussion about proposing `file_system::home_directory()`: https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/g/std-proposals/c/8zH7v7ow5bQ (TL;DR: No such propsal exists afaik)